# Why does Netty pin (register) channels to specific threads in the executor thread pool?

Tags: netty

In coming from Apache Mina, dispatching to IO or worker threads leverage all available threads in the executor thread pool, where Netty works more as a load balancer in registering a channel (connection) to a specific IO or worker thread.  With this model, a channel may have to wait for the pinned thread while there are threads available.  My understanding is that this is done to ensure the message order on the channels, but there are techniques for ensuring the message order without having to pin the threads.  Is there some inherent advantage to the pinning of the channels to specific threads?

I view the pinning of the threads as an issue for the throughput of a server, since there may be idle threads and there may be channels waiting unnecessarily.  Is the pinning of the threads a strong framework principle that can't be easily modified?

Comment: are you talking about pinning IO threads or worker threads that may handle non io ?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that this was an intentional change when going from Netty 3 to Netty 4.  One benefit of this design decision is that it becomes easier to write thread safe handlers.

> There is no well-defined thread model in 3.x although there was an attempt to fix its inconsistency in 3.5. 4.0 defines a strict thread model that helps a user write a ChannelHandler without worrying too much about thread safety.

Explanation of the changes in 4.0

- http://netty.io/wiki/new-and-noteworthy-in-4.0.html#well-defined-thread-model

Something worth reading if you are interested in modifying the behavior

- http://netty.io/wiki/new-and-noteworthy-in-4.0.html#deregistration-and-re-registration-of-a-channel-fromto-an-io-thread